# What are the other games in this series?

Tags: identify-this-game

A few weeks back me and my friends were remembering our childhood games, and it turned out all four of us had at least [one of these themed board game collection books](https://web.archive.org/web/20130515090953/http://howtonotsuckatgamedesign.com/?p=2928). The link has pictures of the book with *superheroes*. I had a book themed with *insects*, and two other friends of mine remember having one with *racing tracks* and *action movie heroes*. I'd like to know what other games were in this series, and possibly find some pictures of them to share with my friends and be all nostalgic for a while.

I very much hope this type of questions is on topic here.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently they were made by Tormont Publishing out of Canada in the early 90s, and they made them with all kinds of themes.

I have been able to find a reference to a disny version, 'game' version and others. Sadly there is no real documentation for any of it, not even a wiki. [This](http://openlibrary.org/publishers/Tormont#page=2) is a partial list of books that Tormont published. You can see a bunch of the game books in there.

[Board game geek](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/11169/giant-game-board-book) has an entry for the 'game' book and a [science fiction version](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/22415/giant-intergalactic-electronic-game-book) which was apparently made in the late 90s.

[Here is an add for a Disney-themed one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2894295847) on Amazon.

It seems they licensed all kinds of material but they must not have been that popular because they do not seem to have survived. There are very few pictures of them out there and copies, when available, range between $40 - $100.

I guess you will have to pick something else to wax nostalgic about.